# How to pass child properties/values to parent component when screen is loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I send property values from child component to parent component when the react app is loaded? I have a parent component called `app.js`, which renders a home component which contains a JSON component. 
When the react app is loaded, my property JSONValue (defined in app.js) holds an empty string. When the react app is loaded, JSONValue in the parent component should contain the value already defined in the child JSON component. How do I manage to send these values from JSON component to APP component on initial render?

The only way I can do this as it is right now, is by changing the value in the react app --> json component. Then it sends the value from child to parent.

So:
The value of JSONValue is defined in JSON component, and is only applied to the JSONValue in app.js when a change happens in JSON component. This should be applied as soon as the react app loads.

APP.JS:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Home from './Components/Home';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component 
{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

      JSONValues: {
        JSONValue: ""
      }
    }

    this.changeJSON = this.changeJSON.bind(this);



changeJSON(e, JSONId)
{
  const elem = e.target;
  const JSONValue = elem.value;

  let tmpJSONValues = this.state.JSONValues;
  tmpJSONValues[JSONId] = JSONValue;

  this.setState(prevState => ({
    JSONValues: tmpJSONValues
  }));
}

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <Home 
            JSONValues={this.state.JSONValues}
            changeJSON={this.changeJSON}
          />
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

HOME.JS:
returns:

```
<div>
  <JSON
    JSONValues={props.JSONValues} 
    changeJSON={props.changeJSON}
   />
</div>
```

JSON.JS:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

    export default class JSON extends Component {
        render() {
            let JSONValue = "";

            if(this.props.JSONValues){
                JSONValue = this.props.JSONValues.JSONValue;
            }

            JSONValue = 'value';

            return (
                <div>
                    <textarea className="json" spellCheck={false}  value={JSONValue}  onChange={(e) =>this.props.changeJSON(e, 'JSONValue')}>

                    </textarea>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you create state in the parent component and then pass the data to the child through props.

In the parent, you also create a changeStateHandler that you also pass to the child component through props.

When the child needs to update its state, it uses the passed in changeStateHandler. The parent then updates its state and passes the new state back to the child through props. The child rerenders when it gets the new props.

This is a simple contrived example:

Demo.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export const Parent = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    return (
      <div>
          <div>Parent says the count is now: {counter}</div>
          <Child counter={counter} handleCounter={setCounter} />
      </div>
    );
};

const Child = ({counter, handleCounter}) => {
    const incrementCounter = () => handleCounter(counter++); 
    const decrementCounter = () => handleCounter(counter--);
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={incrementCounter}>+</button>
            <button onClick={decrementCounter}>-</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a function through child props to set the parent state on mount as below:

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    const jsonString = '{"foo":"bar"}';
    this.props.onMount(jsonString)
  }
  
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}


class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    jsonData: null
  }
  
  setJson = jsonData => this.setState({ jsonData });
  
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <span>parent's state jsonData:</span>
        <pre>{this.state.jsonData}</pre>
        <Child onMount={this.setJson} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```